# How to create a generic object type that uses the key as a specific value instead of type string without declaring the type?

Tags: typescript

Is it possible to create a generic object type that would force the keys to be used as values internally?

For example, if I want an object to have the id that matches the key I would use something like the code below:

```js
export type ObjectWithId<
  T extends string,
  E extends Record<string, unknown>
> = {
  [K in T]: { id: K } & E;
};

type IdKeys = 'dog' | 'cat';

const animals: ObjectWithId<IdKeys, { title: string }> = {
  dog: { id: 'dog', title: 'Some title' },
  cat: { id: 'cat', title: 'Another title' },
};
```

But I wonder if there is a solution that could work without the need to declare the `IdKeys` and therefore would infer these values from the object.

e.g.

```js
const animals: ObjectWithId<{ title: string }> = {
  dog: { id: 'dog', title: 'Some title' },
  cat: { id: 'cat', title: 'Another title' },
};
```

If I can't do it only with a type and need to use a Constrained Identity Function would then it still be possible to declare the type for the rest of the object?

e.g.

```js
validateObjectWithId<{ title: string }>(
  { cat: { id: 'cat', title: 'Another title' } }
)
```

I would like to use `validateObjectWithId()` as a helper to validate only the id so it can be used with all sorts of data but still be able to declare the type for the rest of the data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to create extra builder function in order to make this type validation:

```js
const foo = <
    Id extends PropertyKey,
    Value extends Record<string, unknown>,
    >(a: Record<Id, { id: Id } & Value>) => a


// ok
foo({
    dog: { id: 'dog', title: 'Some title' },
    cat: { id: 'cat', title: 'Another title' },
})

// error
foo({
    dog: { id: 'cat', title: 'Some title' }, 
    cat: { id: 'cat', title: 'Another title' },
})
```

Above approach is good, but it might be even better. As you might have noticed, if `id` is wrong, the whole row is highlighted.

Consider this example:

```js
type ErrorMessage<T extends string> = `ID property should be equal to ${T}`

type ValidateId<Obj extends Record<PropertyKey, { id: PropertyKey }>> = {
    /**
     * Iterate throught eahc Key
     */
    [Key in keyof Obj]:
    /**
     * Check whether [id] property is equal to Key
     */
    Obj[Key]['id'] extends Key
    /**
     * If yes, leave object as it is
     */
    ? Obj[Key]
    /**
     * Itherwise, replace [id] value with readable error message
     */
    : Omit<Obj[Key], 'id'> & {
        id: ErrorMessage<Key & string>
    }
}
const foo = <
    Id extends PropertyKey,
    Value extends Record<string, unknown>,
    Data extends Record<Id, { id: Id } & Value>
>(a: ValidateId<Data>) => a

foo({
    dog: { id: 'dog2', title: 'Some title' }, // only ID property is highlighted
    cat: { id: 'cat', title: 'Another title' },
})
```

[Playground](https://tsplay.dev/w23gbN)

Now, only `id` property is highlighted with nice error message.

If you are interested in this approach, you can check my articles: [Type inference on function arguments](https://catchts.com/infer-arguments) and [Validators](https://catchts.com/validators)

---

**UPDATE  September 6 2022**

If you want to make this function fully generic and be able to use explicit generic, you can try this approach:

```js
type ErrorMessage<T extends string> = `ID property should be equal to ${T}`

type ValidateId<Obj extends Record<PropertyKey, { id: PropertyKey }>> = {
    [Key in keyof Obj]:
    Obj[Key]['id'] extends Key
    ? Obj[Key]
    : Omit<Obj[Key], 'id'> & {
        id: ErrorMessage<Key & string>
    }
}

type Json =
    | null
    | string
    | number
    | boolean
    | Array<JSON>
    | {
        [prop: string]: Json
    }

const foo = <Value extends Json>() => <
    Id extends PropertyKey,
    Data extends Record<Id, { id: Id } & Value>
>(a: ValidateId<Data>) => a

const withTitle = foo<{ title: string }>();

const result = withTitle({
    dog: { id: 'dog', title: 'Some title' }, // only ID property is highlighted
    cat: { id: 'cat', title: 'Another title' },
})
```

**P.S.**
If you don't like using function and still want to achieve what you want, my answer is - no. It is impossible in typescript generate such constraint without knowing upfront your keys

Comment: Thank you for explaning that it wasn't possible what I wanted but also providing alternative solutions!

Comment: Is it possible to still declare the type for the rest of the object? e.g. `foo<{ title: string }>({ cat: { id: 'cat', title: 'Another title' } })`.

I would like to use `foo()` as a helper to validate only the id so it can be used with all sorts of data but still be able to declare the type for the rest of the data.

Comment: Please update a question with expected results

Comment: Sure thing, the question has been updated with the expected results.

Comment: Do yo want to make generic function and make possible to use explicit generics or you always want to use `{title: string}` ?

Comment: I need a generic function and make it possible to use explicit generics.

Comment: Thanks for updating your answer with the extra example!